# using prestashop's 1.7 smarty url tag in a from action property

Tags: php, smarty, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I'm using prestashop 1.7.2.1 to build a module with a front controller.

what I'm trying to do is to add the smarty`{url}` tag to the action property of the form. the problem is that once I submit the form all the get parameters that are provided in action property of the from are erased. this is a normal behaviour in html.

this is my code:

```
<form id="car-type-form" action="{url entity='module' name='tuxinmodcartype' controller='cartypeproducts'}" method="get">
    <div id="company-name-input-form-group" class="form-group row">
        <label for="company-name-input" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Company</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="company-name-input" name="company_name" placeholder="Company" aria-label="Company" required="required"/>
        </div>
    </div>
...
</form>
```

In general I can paste that smarty `{url}` tag to a variable. on submit to add the values of the form fields dynamically to the variable I created and use it to redirect instead of allowing the form to submit.

I just don't know if this is the best solution.

maybe there is something that I missed.

any ideas?

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for now what I did is to add hidden input elements to the form based on the created url string.

I have this on the first line of my template file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var carTypeProductsUrl='{url entity='module' name='tuxinmodcartype' controller='cartypeproducts'}';
</script>
```

and on the submit function I added the following code:

```
...
if (isError) {
            event.preventDefault();
        } else {
            $('.hidden-form-params').remove();
            var params = carTypeProductsUrl.substr(carTypeProductsUrl.indexOf('?')+1).split('&');
            params.forEach((paramStr)=>{
                var paramsArray = paramStr.split('=');
                const paramKey = paramsArray[0];
                const paramvalue = paramsArray[1];
                $('#car-type-form').append(`<input type="hidden" name="${paramKey}" value="${paramvalue}" class="hidden-form-params" />`);
            });
        }
```

this method feels a bit.. hacky?! :) I just want to make sure this is the way to go